# Merge value in string using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making string contains values. I have company name, product and its value. I want to store  these value in string but if user choose same product of same company then I want to only append product no only.

current string value `TATA#434#tyre,TATA#234#door,TATA#687#tyre,` and it should be as

```
TATA#434,687#tyre,TATA#234#door
```

as we can see user choose same company with same production, only product no. is different so we need to append only product no.

if customer choose all four product then string should be read like this

```
TATA#434,687#tyre,TATA#234#door,Maruti#8776#door
```

company and product can be increase. also in last entry how to remove ",".

Here is attached [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54nnw/).

**Code**

```
var str="";
$('a').click(function(){
var el= $(this).parent();
str += el.find('#brand').text() + "#" + el.find('#no').text() + "#" + el.find('#product').text() +",";
console.log(str)    
})
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an `array` if you're implementing a `csv` format? It would make it much easier... You could always just `.join()` it later when you needed it displayed.

Comment: _“I want to store these value in string”_ – _storing_ values in a string is a wrong approach already. Choose an _appropriate_ data structure for storage; make it a string only if you have to _display_ it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My real advice would be to use an `object`. Why? Because it makes your **data manipulation** SO much easier my friend.

Use something like:

```
function car(val1,val2,val3,val4) {
this.val1 = val1;
this.val2 = val2;
this.val3 = val3;
this.val4 = val4;
}
```

**Now we can just make one with:**

```
var item1 = new car("TATA#434","687#tyre","TATA#234#door","Maruti#8776#door");
```

### Now you can change whatever you want.

If you would like further guidance on how to **display** this in the format you've suggested, more than happy to help.

Your solution involves many `RegEx`... which can turn sour quickly. As a large scale developer, I advice against this if there is *any* chance your values will change format in the future.

---

#### Using Arrays:

**Here is a use case:**

http://jsfiddle.net/k6XFy/1/

```
var a = ["TATA#434","687#tyre","TATA#234#door","Maruti#8776#door"];
function display(x){
    alert(x);
}
alert(a[1]);
a[1] = "Convert";
alert(a[1]);

alert(a);
```

---

#### Edit:

You can join the array like so:

```
var a = ["TATA#434","687#tyre","TATA#234#door","Maruti#8776#door"];
function display(x){
    alert(x);
}
var b = a.join(',');
alert(b);
```

View here: http://jsfiddle.net/k6XFy/3/

Comment: I use array for this, but not getting logic to how to get desire result as describe above

Comment: Fine, `array` it is. One sec.

Comment: i am getting result like this : ["TATA#434#tyre", "TATA#234#door", "TATA#687#tyre", "Maruti#8776#door"]. how to merge the same values

Comment: Updated. Hopefully this helps. It will convert `indexed` values in the `array`. Please select the **green checkbox** next to the **voting arrows** if this has helped. And I won't write your code for you, but one further example, one sec.

Comment: Adding *another* explanation for you, as well as the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not store it in an object?

This is how I would store it.

`{TATA: { 434: 'tyre', 234: 'door' }, Maruti: { 8776: 'door' }}`

If you need to use it as a string, loop through it constructing the string when you need it.

EDIT:

I'm not sure the exact context, but perhaps this would even make sense:

`{TATA: { tyre: [434,687], door: [234] }, Maruti: { door: [8776] }}`

or

`{ tyre: { TATA: [434,687] }, door: { Maruti: [8776], TATA: [234] }}`

Comment: Thanks. I will use object like the way you mentioned it. May this will solve my problem